# Переменная в форме html

Tags: html, javascript

Помогите пожалуйста. Нужно чтобы этот код заработал.
Там где document.getElementById('text') должно подтягиваться значение которое пользователь укажет в форме.

Использовать тег script нельзя.
Что я делаю не так?

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="text" value="">
<button onclick="window.open('http://localhost/history&id=' + document.getElementById('text');"> проверить </button>
 </form>
```

Сорри за ламерство :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="text" value="">
<button onclick="window.open('http://localhost/history&id=' + document.getElementById('text').value); return false;"> проверить</button>
</form>
```

[Пример на jsfillde](http://jsfiddle.net/bsFKR/)